# Mongoose ignore callback on findOne if no result

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to check if a user is already existing in my DB. For now, I have a very simple controller in express :

```
app.post('/signup', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  User.findOne(
      { email: req.body.credentials.email },
      function (_err, _data) {
          res.status(409).send('hello');
      }
  );
})
```

If a user indeed exists with the email from the request, a 409 status is sent. But if no user exist matching the email, no response is ever sent. Is this normal behavior ? If yes, how do I callback a function for when I have no result on the `findOne` ?

Using Mongoose 4.7.7

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, a `schema.post('findOne', function)` was defined for the `User` model and `next()` was not always called.